# Apache named virtual host not working after changing port

Tags: apache, jboss, localhost

I have a jboss server and an apache web server on the same machine. Jboss has to stay listening on port 80, so I had to switch which port apache listened on. Before, when it was listening on port 80, everything worked fine. I set up a virtual host for a website I'm working on, and I was able to use the URL for that site as a I defined it in the virtual host file and my hosts file (I'm using Windows). After I changed the port it listened on, I get the following error:

Problem loading page: Unable to connect

I've restarted the server, restarted my machine, changed the port to several different numbers that weren't being used for anything else, and I even tried changing the localhost IP address from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.2 to see if that would help, but none of this has worked. I changed the port in both httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf, but nothing has really worked. I checked the IP address for the site with ping, and it showed that I'm using the right one. I would really appreciate some help because nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Likely a local firewall issue. You should only need to change Listen, ServerName and <virtualhost>.  You can use lsof or netstat to confirm the listening port.

Comment: sorry, Listen, ServerName and what?

Comment: sorry, VirtualHost. I had the <> tags unescaped